# Dynamic path in homebox module

Tags: 7, dashboard

I am using Drupal 7, I recently used homebox module to create my dashboard for the users. While creating paths in homebox, I found that using '%' or '*' as dynamic path (user/%/dashboard) threw a validation error.

The strange thing was, the drupal.org has the same path for its dashboard too, I am not sure how this could be possible with homebox, when '%' or '*' cannot be used in the path definition.

Would be great if any one can answer about using dynamic paths in the homebox module.